How do I run cli commands on Windows or Linux in postgresql?
I want to delete or download files from db server where postgresql is installed. To do this, I want to use a function in postgresql to run cli commands on Windows or Linux.
When installing postgresql, it is difficult to install anything other than the plpgsql extension that is installed by default.
How can I run cli commands on Windows or Linux?
And what are some other ways to delete or download files?

I'm trying to follow. So you want to use postgres (which I presume has some table of shell commands you want to run) and you want a way to have postgres execute one of the commands on either Linux or Windows - even though the Linux shell and windows cmd.exe are completely different? Which leaves me confused on why you are trying to issue commands from postgres to any shell -- when you can simply use the shell to begin with? What am I missing? The question needs a bit more clarity and explanation.


Doing work on the OS directly is a big security risk, you should think about whether  you really want to do that. 2) If you do want to do this  then you can  use the plpython3u and the untrusted version of plperl languages. There is also plsh where is a third part extension, also not sure if it would work on Windows. 3) The safer bet would be to push the data into the database, not pull it in.

